# Spectrum of a special unitary operator $U$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ be an orthonormal basis of Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $U$ be an unitary operator such that $U e_n = e_{n+1}$, then what is the spectrum of $U$?

First I know $\sigma(U)\subset S^1$...

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

1. if $B$ is any (infinite) set, then one can form a Hilbert space of sequences with index set $B$, defined by
   $$
   \ell^{2}(B)=\left\{x:B \stackrel{x}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{C}: \sum_{b \in B}\left| x(b)\right|^{2}<\infty\right\}.
   $$
   The summation over $B$ is here defined by
   $$
   \sum_{b \in B}|x(b)|^{2}=\sup \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|x\left(b_{n}\right)\right|^{2}
   $$
   the supremum being taken over all finite subsets of B. (From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)).
2. $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$.

Comment: I’m a little new to this, can you define what $l^2(Z)$ and $S^1$ are?

Comment: @paulinho I've edited.

Comment: The question has been anwered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/spectrum-of-the-right-shift-operator-on-ell2-bf-z) already. In particular consider Robert Israel's comment: Use the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}:L^2(S^1)\rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ to turn $U$ into a multiplication operator $f\mapsto zf$ on $L^2(S^1)$ (with same spectrum). It is then easy to check that $\sigma(U)=S^1$.

Comment: @JanBohr Thank you very much! Could you please think about this problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3736344/509160